# Socket C++ Read Erro

Tags: c++, socket

Estou desenvolvendo um programinha em C++ usando Socket, o problema é que quando o cliente enviar alguma informação para mim eu não recebo. Na verdade o programa trava.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <unistd.h>




int main(int argc, char *argv[])  {
    int socket_;
    struct sockaddr_in config;
    socklen_t config_len;

    socket_ = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 6);
    struct hostent *hostname = gethostbyname("127.0.0.1");
    if (socket_ < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Deu Merda AA";
    }
    config.sin_family = hostname->h_addrtype;
    config.sin_port = htons(10001);
    config.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *) hostname->h_addr);
    bzero(&(config.sin_zero), 8);
    config_len = sizeof(config);


    std::cout << "Bind\n";
    if(int e = bind(socket_, (struct sockaddr * )&config, config_len) < 0){
        std::cerr << "Deu Merda A";
        return e;
    }

    std::cout << "Listen\n";
    if(int e = listen(socket_, 5) < 0) {
        std::cerr << "Deu Merda B";
        return e;
    }

    std::cout << "Esperando Cliente:\n";
    int client_socket = accept(socket_,(struct sockaddr * )&config, &config_len);
    std::cout << "Numero do Cliente " << client_socket << "\n";
    if(client_socket < 0){
        std::cerr << "Deu Merda C";
    }else {
        char *buffer;
        bzero(buffer, 201);
        std::cout << read(client_socket,buffer,201) << "\n";
    }

}
```

Minha Saída:

```
Bind
Listen
Esperando Cliente:
Numero do Cliente 4

Process finished with exit code 10
```

O cliente recebe o erro de `Broken Pipe` ou seja, que a conexão caiu. Mas o que tem de errado no meu código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pedro, tenho um servidor http implementado com sockets multiplataforma em c++ mas não utilizo a função read que está utilizando, apesar de utilizar o recv que possui estrutura parecida.

```
int recv (int __fd, void *__buf, size_t __n, int __flags)
```

Onde temos os seguintes pontos:

0) O retorno é o número de bytes recebido. (um retorno negativo é um erro)

1) O primeiro parâmetro (__fd) é o descritor de arquivo (vulgo número da socket) que você está utilizando para esta conexão.

2) Um ponteiro para um buffer (eu particularmente utilizar um buffer de 4096 bytes, do tipo char)

3) A quantidade de bytes do buffer (4096 no meu caso).

4) As flags para recebimento (particularmente nunca precisei mexer neste parâmetro, sempre uso por padrão ZERO (0).

Como o retorno da função indica Broken Pipe é necessário também verificar que tipo de cliente está sendo utilizado para conectar ao servidor e se a implementação dele está compatível com a tua.

Comment: Era exatamente este problema, além de que quando se cria uma variável no if por algum motivo sempre vem 0. Muito obrigado.

Comment: não é idiomático usar identificadores começando com dois underlines, esses identificadores em princípio são reservados para a implementação da linguagem (runtime, bibliotecas, etc)